# What does colon in this snippet from matlab specifies?

Tags: matlab

```
mse=sum((dfusion(:)-approx(:)).^2)/prod(size(dfusion));
```

MSE of fused images is being calculated. The dfusion is the inverse wavelet transform coefficient value of the fused image. There are 2 images and one a final fused image. What does the colon in this mean?

Answer (score 0):

`a(:)` means treat `a` as a 1-D column vector. For example:

```
>> a = [1, 2; 3, 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4

>> a(:)

ans =

     1
     3
     2
     4
```